# Jquery Events Lists Order by Date

Tags: jquery, list, events, date

I have list of upcoming events with dates, Is there any JQuery codes/plugins to:

1) Order list of events by latest dates first.
2) Let latest event disappear by a given time at the day of event.
3) Say I had 15 lists of upcoming events for the year, I want just 6 list of events to appear at every giving time.

```
<div id="event">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="single's_weekend.html">Single's WeekEnd</a><p>Sat &amp; Sun, Nov 10th - 11th 2013</p></li>
        <li><a href="women's_conference.html">Women's Con.</a><p>Sunday, May 20th 2013</p></li> 
        <li><a href="children's_day.html">Children's Day</a><p>Sunday, May 27th 2013</p></li>   
        <li><a href="couple's_retreat.html">Couple's Retreat</a><p>Fri-Sun, June 1st - 3rd 2013</p></li> 
        <li><a href="week_of_prayer.html">Week of Prayer</a><p>Mon-Sun, Sept 3rd - 8th 2013</p></li>
        <li><a href="annual_conference_2012.html">Annual Conference 2013</a><p>Wed-Sun, October 3rd - 7th 2013</p></li> 
    </ul>                       
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a general format for the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code... jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KrTNJ/1/

Three functions are implemented:

**sortEvents**

Sorts the lists in order of end date and adds an id to each li element.

**removeOldEvents**

Removes the events which are ending until today. You can call this in a timer or something, or during startup. This ONLY works if sortEvents have been already executed.

**displaySome(count)**

Displays only "count" entries. This ONLY works if sortEvents have been already executed.

---

```
// Uses jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var month_index = function(target) {
        target = target.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return jQuery.inArray(true, jQuery.map(months, function(s) {
            return s.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(target) > -1;
        })) + 1;
    };

    function getKeys(obj) {
        var keys = [];
        for(var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        }

        return keys;
    }

    function sortEvents() {
        eventList = new Object();

        $("#event ul li").each(function(index, value) { 
            dates = $(this).children("p")[0];
            dates = $(dates).text().split(",")[1].trim();

            m = dates.split(" ");

            if(dates.search("-") != -1) {
                m.splice(1, 2);
            }

            m[1] = m[1].substring(0, m[1].length - 2);

            month = month_index(m[0])

            id = m[2] + "-" + (month < 10 ? "0" + month : month) + "-" + (m[1] < 10 ? "0" + m[1] : m[1]);

            eventList[id] = "<li id='" + id + "'>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";
        });

        eventKeys = getKeys(eventList).sort();
        $("#event ul").empty();

        for(i = 0; i < eventKeys.length; i++) {
            $("#event ul").append(eventList[eventKeys[i]]);
        }
    }

    function removeOldEvents() {
        $("#event ul li").each(function(index, value) { 
            a = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
            d = new Date(a[0], (a[1] - 1), a[2]);

            g = new Date();
            g.setHours(0,0,0,0);

            c = (d > g) - (g > d);

            if(c < 1) {
                // Remove
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

        displaySome(6);
    }

    function displaySome(count) {
        $("#event ul").find('li:gt(' + (count - 1) + ')').hide();
    }

    sortEvents();

    removeOldEvents();

    displaySome(6);
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for he code, it work well. The Lord bless you real.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using database to store all these events, you can use **order by date desc** and select dates that are greater than current date (**where date > today**) and limit them only to 6 (using **limit by** clause)

Comment: what about if I am not using a database to store these events. is there not a way around it?